# Are there Anchors in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I'm coding an e-recruiting platform in SAPUI5 at the moment and getting mad about a clean navigation.

At the moment the different data (personal data, experience, attachments,...) is displayed in its own panel that you can expand or not. I think it would be nice (especially mobile) if you can jump to the section you selected. I looked for some kind of anchors or something like that but after long search I couldn't find anything like that.
Is there a chance to set anchors like in HTML to navigate to the right panel?

Answer (score 2):

As of SAPUI5/OpenUI5 version 1.30 there is a [sap.m.Wizard](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Wizard/preview) control which reflects your use case:

[image: sap.m.Wizard]

If you want to test it you can try the latest OpenUI5 Snapshot version 1.29.x from the official [download page](http://openui5.org/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this might work.

Assuming you have given Ids of Panels like following

for personal data Panel :  "PersonalDataPanel";
for experience Panel :  "ExperiencePanel";
for attachment Panel :  "AttachmentPanel";

```
var oLink1 = new sap.ui.commons.Link({
    text: "Link to PersonalData", 
    href: "#PersonalDataPanel",
});
var oLink2 = new sap.ui.commons.Link({
    text: "Link to Experience", 
    href: "#ExperiencePanel",
});
var oLink3 = new sap.ui.commons.Link({
    text: "Link to Attachment", 
    href: "#AttachmentPanel",
});
```

**OR**

Replace links with raw "HTML" like :

```
var oLink1 =  sap.ui.core.HTML({
      content: "<a href='#PersonalDataPanel'>PersonalDataPanel</a>"
});
```